# How to automate FB events creation

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Does anyone know how to create an event through the FB API?

I see old documentation of graph.facebook.com/v2.11/official_events where it was possible. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/official-events/getting-started

But the new documentation only shows how to get all events of a page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v15.0/event/#Creating

Is anyone succesfull with FB page event creation? Creating all our events by hand is a hassle.

Tried multiple endpoints and read above documentation, but getting nowhere with all the API calls I make.

Answer (score 0):

this page makes it look like you have to apply to use this api:
https://developers.facebook.com/products/official-events-api/

and the application form says:

> Thank you for your interest in the Official Events API product. Due to
> COVID-19, we are temporarily pausing new integrations with partners,
> but you are welcome to complete the form below. Please note that
> responses to this form are monitored but you may not receive a direct
> response.